# how to convert the $filter in angularJS pipe in Angular 5.0

Tags: angular

I have this code in angularJS

```
return $filter('date')(dataItem.dataContext.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z') + '<br>' +
       $filter('translate')('LOGIN_ATTEMPTS.SUCCESS') + ': ' + dataItem.dataContext.success;
```

And now we are using angular 5.0. How to convert this to work with angular 5.0.
There is no $filter in angular. I am looking to pipe but couldn't make it work
Please help

Comment: use the pipe operator

Answer (score 0):

You can use [date pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) in angular2+ in the template

```
 <!--output 'Jun 15, 2015'-->
    <p>Today is {{today | date}}</p>

<!--output 'Monday, June 15, 2015'-->
    <p>Or if you prefer, {{today | date:'fullDate'}}</p>

    <!--output '9:43 AM'-->
    <p>The time is {{today | date:'shortTime'}}</p>

    <!--output 'Monday, June 15, 2015 at 9:03:01 AM GMT+01:00' -->
    <p>The full date/time is {{today | date:'full'}}</p>

    <!--output 'Lundi 15 Juin 2015 à 09:03:01 GMT+01:00'-->
    <p>The full date/time in french is: {{today | date:'full':'':'fr'}}</p>

    <!--output '2015-06-15 05:03 PM GMT+9'-->
    <p>The custom date is {{today | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a z':'+0900'}}</p>

    <!--output '2015-06-15 09:03 AM GMT+9'-->
    <p>The custom date with fixed timezone is {{fixedTimezone | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a z':'+0900'}}</p>
```

And there are few [built in pipes](https://angular.io/api?type=pipe) in angular. And you can create your own [custome pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes) as well.